# Confidence interval for a linear regression with non-normal data

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I'm doing linear regressions in R with non-normal data, so I'd like to know how to determine a confidence interval or measure the coefficient's spread. The code I'm using is the simplest for doing a linear regression:

```
lm(y~x, data=DataBase)
```

If I use the `confint()` function, the C.I. given is valid for normal data so... how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried bootstrapping?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that method. Can you write a brief example for constructing C.I. from a linear regression? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of how to bootstrap CIs in R.  There are a couple intervals you could use, but I recommend the Bias Corrected Intervals (BCa)

````
library(boot)


get_coefs<-function(data, inds){
  model = lm(y~x, data = data[inds,])
  coef(model)[1]
}


x = rnorm(100)
y = 2*x + 1 + rnorm(100)
d = data.frame(x, y)
b = boot(data = d, statistic = get_coefs, 1000)

boot::boot.ci(b)
> boot::boot.ci(b)
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 1000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot::boot.ci(boot.out = b)

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 0.7742,  1.1238 )   ( 0.7687,  1.1220 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 0.7880,  1.1413 )   ( 0.7771,  1.1254 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
```
````

Comment: Excellent explanation!!! Thanks!